# Can burrowed swarm hosts be picked up by graviton beam?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is it possible for phoenixes that have detection to be able to pick up burrowed swarm hosts to kill/neutralize them?

Answer (score 9):

Well, phoenixes can pick up borrowed units, so I guess swarm hosts don't count as different

See here: [wiki entry for phoenixes](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Phoenix)

> ... 
>   Burrowed zerg units will be unburrowed by the ability, and will reburrow when they fall back to the ground...

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is possible.

They tested this is the following youtube video: [SC2 Mythbusters Episode 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4okHGZNnNc8&feature=player_detailpage#t=135s)

Comment: Perfect video to show this!

Answer (score 1):

I have seen it happen in casts in the beta. I am not sure if that ability has been patched out or is still relative, but my guess would be that it is still possible.